# How to sort data in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

I am trying to sort the data in gridview

everything is working fine but numeric column(Marks) taking sorting for 1st number only

**Code:**

```
 protected void gvTrHty_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.gviewSorting(e.SortExpression);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string arg_15_0 = ex.Message;
        }
    }

 private void gviewSorting(string strSortExp)
    {
        if (this.ViewState["dvTrain"] == null)
        {
            DataSet dataSet = this.BindTraining();
            dv = dataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        else
        {
            DataSet dataSet2 = (DataSet)this.ViewState["dvTrain"];
            TrainingHistory.dv = dataSet2.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        if (TrainingHistory.sortorder)
        {
            TrainingHistory.sortorder = false;
            TrainingHistory.dv.Sort = strSortExp + " DESC";
        }
        else
        {
            TrainingHistory.sortorder = true;
            TrainingHistory.dv.Sort = strSortExp;
        }
        this.BindData(TrainingHistory.dv);
    }
```

If I have values in Mark(column) in gridview

```
   Marks----> When I click this for sorting it's taking     Marks     

    1                                                         1                            
    8                         1st number only sorted  --->    12
    40                                                        21 
    12                                                        40
    21                                                        8
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwf94875(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It's doing alphabetical sort, instead of numerical.  Is the Marks column being converted to text somewhere?

Comment: Do you use binding list as a data source? If not, are you able to?

Answer (score 0):

It is treating your "numerical" data as a string and doing the sort against this string value, thus "40" is less than "8".

Your options are:

1. Put leading zeroes on the numeric field values, which is probably a no-go for obvious reasons, this would allow the existing sort to work correctly. I suppose you could temporarily put leading zeroes and then rip them out after the sort, but this sounds like a headache.
2. Implement your own sorting logic, like this:

   ```
   public sealed class GenericComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
   {
       public enum SortOrder
       {
           Ascending = 0,
           Descending = 1
       }

       private string sortColumn;
       private SortOrder sortingOrder;

       public string SortColumn
       {
           get
           {
               return this.sortColumn;
           }
       }

       public SortOrder SortingOrder
       {
           get
           {
               return this.sortingOrder;
           }
       }

       public GenericComparer(string theSortColumn, SortOrder theSortingOrder)
       {
           this.sortColumn = theSortColumn;
           this.sortingOrder = theSortingOrder;
       }

       public int Compare(T x, T y)
       {
           PropertyInfo thePropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(this.sortColumn);
           IComparable object1 = (IComparable)thePropertyInfo.GetValue(x, null);
           IComparable object2 = (IComparable)thePropertyInfo.GetValue(y, null);

           if (this.sortingOrder == SortOrder.Ascending)
           {
               return object1.CompareTo(object2);
           }
           else
           {
               return object2.CompareTo(object1);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now in your call to `.Sort()` method, you pass a new instance of this helper class (passing it the column you want to sort by and the direction you want to sort - ascending or descending).

Since the comparer logic above uses generics, you can pass whatever type you want to sort by (i.e. `int`, `DateTime`, or even entire domain objects).